# Parse Date, Month, and Year from Javascript "Date" form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, date

I am using the following for a user to input a date in a form:

```
<input name="name" type="date" id="id"/>
```

I am wondering if there is a way to parse the Day, Month, and Year from this and set them into different variables. I am trying to use only Javascript, not PHP.

The 3 variables would be integers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best option, if you're accepting input and converting it to a [date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), either split by part or as a `Date` object, is to simply construct a new `Date` object by passing it the input value:

```
var input = document.getElementById( 'id' ).value;
var d = new Date( input );

if ( !!d.valueOf() ) { // Valid date
    year = d.getFullYear();
    month = d.getMonth();
    day = d.getDate();
} else { /* Invalid date */ }
```

This way you can leverage `Date`s handling of multiple input formats - it will take YYYY/MM/DD, YYYY-MM-DD, MM/DD/YYYY, even full text dates ( 'October 25, 2013' ), etc. without having you write your own parser. Valid dates are then easily checked by `!!d.valueOf()` - true if it's good, false if not :)

Comment: getMonth() will return 0 for January, 1 for February... 11 for December, so you'll have to add 1 to get the correct month number

Answer (score 4):

You will want to split the value on '-', not '/'. E.g.,

```
$( "input" ).change(function(e) {
   var vals = e.target.value.split('-');
   var year = vals[0];
   var month = vals[1];
   var day = vals[2];
   console.info(day, month, year);
});
```

Here is a jsbin of a working example: http://jsbin.com/ayAjufo/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:-

```
function parseDate(input) {
  var str= input.split('/');
  return new Date(str[0], str[1]-1, str[2]); 
}
```

`str[1]-1` as months start from 0.

You may also check **[Date.parse(string)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)** but this implemetation dependent.

Comment: This logic seems to work, however when I run this, with the input of a date from the form, I get, "Invalid Date." I think the input is supposed to be a string, is this correct?

Comment: You need to parse a date in yyyy/mm/dd format to get it working!

Comment: And yes it has to be string!

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression improvements with ES9. You can use like that.

```
const  
reDate = /([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})/,
match = reDate.exec('2019-05-29'),
year = match[1],  //2019
month = match[2], //05
day = match[3];   //29
```