# javascript how to display a input dates month, day and year in separate lines?

Tags: javascript, date-parsing

How do I parse a date in javascript to out put a users date input to display in html in seperate lines such as:

> Month:
>   Day:
>   Year:

I am using:

```
<button type="button" onclick="date_test()">Process</button>
<br> <p id="iop"></p>
```

Comment: Please share your 'input' and 'output' format

Comment: Please share your code and where are you stuck

Comment: Im using <button type="button" onclick="date_test()">Process</button>
<br> as input and 
<p id="iop"></p> tags as out put

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp check this out for reference about javascript dates.  
you will have to use a combination of function provided by the date object.

Comment: @ElieNassif—please don't reference w3schools, MDN or ECMA-262 are much better references.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Date, Month, and Year from Javascript "Date" form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597361/parse-date-month-and-year-from-javascript-date-form)

Comment: Have you seen this, https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vphj34on/).

Code:

```
var dateObj = new Date();
var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="<p>Month:"+month+"</p><p>Day:"+day+"</p><p>Year:"+year+"</p>";
```

```js
var dateObj = new Date();
var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="<p>Month:"+month+"</p><p>Day:"+day+"</p><p>Year:"+year+"</p>";
```

```html
<div id="output">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for all the input on my question. csharpbd, your response was exactly what I was trying to achieve. I appreciate your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var date = new Date(),
  locale = "en-us",
  month = date.toLocaleString(locale, {
    month: "long"
  }),
  day = date.toLocaleString(locale, {
    day: "numeric"
  }),
  year = date.toLocaleString(locale, {
    year: "numeric"
  });
$("#month").append(month);
$("#day").append(day);
$("#year").append(year);
```

```css
.date {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date">
  <span id="month">Month: </span>

  <span id="day">Day: </span>

  <span id="year">Year: </span>
</div>
```