# How to get just year (month, date...) from input type="datetime-local"?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am making the code in JavaScript, that calculates Julian day at the inputted date. It is using a Jean Meeus algorithm (http://www.agopax.it/Libri_astronomia/pdf/Astronomical%20Algorithms.pdf - page 61). I have made HTML tag "input type="datetime-local"" to access user inputting date and time. I want to get just year, month, date, hour and minute. Data must be stored in the variables apart. But I don't know how to do it.

I have already seen W3 pages, StackOverflow page, etc. I haven't found any answer. (I didn't understand even page [Parse Date, Month, and Year from Javascript "Date" form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597361/parse-date-month-and-year-from-javascript-date-form).)

```
<head>
  <script>
    var x = document.getElementById("JulianDayData").value;
    document.getElementById("JulianDayDisplay").innerHTML = x;
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="datetime-local" name="JulianDayData" id="JulianDayData">
  <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="Function()">
  <p id="JulianDataDisplay"></p>
</body>
```

Any answers?

Comment: `But I can't` - what exactly goes wrong? Are you getting any error in the console?

Comment: No, I just don't know how to store year (month...) into the variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Date, Month, and Year from Javascript "Date" form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597361/parse-date-month-and-year-from-javascript-date-form)

Comment: @Mosh Feu Maybe it is, maybe it isn't... But I didn't understand this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597361/parse-date-month-and-year-from-javascript-date-form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert the [`DOMstring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) that the input returns into a `Date` object before you can extract the parts you want from it.

```
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("JulianDayData").value;
    var dateObj = new Date(x);
    var year = dateObj.getFullYear();
    var month = dateObj.getMonth();
    // etc
</script>
```